# sftp connection over esp8266 module

Tags: at-command, esp8266

I am trying to make a sftp connection using esp8266 wifi module but I am facing problems. First I successfully connected esp8266 to my router then I tried making tcp connection to sftp server by using following command

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","demo@test.rebex.net",22
```

but I always get "DNS FAIL" reply from esp8266. How can I make a sftp connection using esp8266 wifi module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/CIPSTART the syntax of the `AT+CIPSTART` command is

```
AT+CIPSTART=type,addr,port
```

Your "address" parameter must be just the hostname. It seems you're putting a URL there with a username (`demo@test.rebex.net`). The hostname should just be `test.rebex.net`, right? The literal hostname `demo@test.rebex.net` does not exist and can therefore not be DNS-resolved, which explains the error. The authentication as the user `demo` is handled in the protocol run then.

Note however that SFTP is a complex protocol. That `CIPSTART` command just opens a raw TCP socket to that hostname and that port for you. Specifically, issuing that command does not execute any high-level protocol logic for you. It's just a socket that you can write and read to. If you mean by SFTP `FTP over SSL` you need to be able to make a SSL protocol run with all the cryptography involved. If by SFTP you mean `Secure File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)` you need an SSH implementation (and rather similar cryptographic primitives). These sort of computations are definitely not suitable for an Arduino which just sends AT+ commands, so I would suggest programming the ESP8266 directly. The `esp-open-rtos` has plenty examples for doing SSL connections, but SSH or SFTP is not implemented yet.